# Эффективное использование памяти при использовании MemoryStream

Tags: c#, шифрование, memory-management

У меня на сайте для быстродействия, и уменьшения кол-ва запросов к БД, некоторая чувствительная информация (Ключ шифрования пользователя) будет кэшироваться в Redis.

Но хранить такую информацию в кэше в открытом виде небезопасно, поэтому эта информация перед тем как сохранятся в кэше, будет шифроваться с помощью единого для всех ключа шифрования который сохранен на сервере.

Алгоритм шифрования будет достаточно простым, с использованием MemoryStream, для загрузки ключа шифрования в память, и для дальнейшего использования.

И вот вопрос, можно ли так делать, не сильно ли это скажется на производительности, ведь по сути у пользователя ключ шифрования длиной в 32 байта, и ключа с таким размером практически никак не влияет на память, и даже если пользователей будет миллион, то это все равно практически никак не скажется на производительности. И даже с тем учетом что ключ будет иметь время жизни 30 минут, и сохранятся в кэше по необходимости использования, это все равно ничто, и по сути использовать MemoryStream можно использовать без опасений.

Но зайдя в документацию к MemoryStream, там есть важное примечение :

> This type implements the IDisposable interface, but does not actually have any resources to dispose.
> This means that disposing it by directly calling Dispose() or by using a
> language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic) is not necessary.

И что же это значит, что при использовании MemoryStream вызов Dispose() просто напросто бесполезен, память никогда не высвободится, и будет занимать память ?

Теперь же снова задам вопрос, стоит ли использовать MemoryStream для временного хранения ключа, или можно рассмотреть другие варианты ?

Comment: `память никогда не высвободится` нет, внутри `MemoryStream` это просто массив и память будет спокойно освобождена после `GC`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs

Comment: в документации говорится про то, что у `MemoryStream` нет неуправляемых ресурсов, поэтому и освобождать нечего, а `Dispose` есть потому, что он унаследован от `Stream`.

Comment: А, теперь все понятно. Спасибо за разъяснение @ExplodingKitten

Comment: TL;DR. [RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream). Вот ещё: [ArrayPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-7.0), [MemoryPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryStream` по сути является обычным массивом байт в оболочке, унаследованной от `System.IO.Stream`. Как уже сказали в комментариях, неуправляемых ресурсов там нет, метод `Dispose` просто унаследован и ничего не делает, память освобождается в обычном порядке, как при явном использовании массива байт.

Но кое на что обратить внимание стоит.

Так как внутри обычный линейный массив байт, то на него накладываются ограничения на максимальный размер объекта, как на обычный массив.

Кроме того, если не задать стартовый размер `MemoryStream` явно, то он будет создан какого-то относительно небольшого размера и при добавлении в поток большего числа байт, чем было выделено, массив будет автоматически увеличен в размере путем создания нового массива большего размера и перезаписи данных из предыдущего, что также стоит учитывать чтобы избежать накопления в памяти лишнего мусора довольно приличного размера и количества.

Comment: `List<T>` тоже на массивах ездит, и по точно такому же принципу.

Comment: @aepot угу, там через одного на массивах ездят, а оставшиеся на связных списках. Это ж база, а у нас тут рюшечки синтаксические, чтобы писалось "быстро" и "без ошибок", но к сожалению, часто работает как раз наоборот =))) Под капот лазить и разбираться не модно стало. Понятно что при наличии готового инструмента надо им пользоваться, а не велосипеды строить, но только если он подходит под задачу. Хотя был у меня случай, когда Dictionary с линейным поиском внутри корзины оказался быстрее дерева поиска, хотя казалось бы теория и О-нотация говорят обратное =)))